# setting a condition on MATLAB ode45 output

Tags: matlab

I want to solve a system of differential equations using ode45 , for (many) parameters in MATLAB to investigate the behavior of solutions with coefficients of the equation .I want to find the parameters **for which the solution absolute value doesn't get  larger than some given number** . The script has a for loop and solves the system for given parameters one after another(in some limited time span (independent variable is time)) .

Now,my question is that "how can I set a condition on ode45 to "detect" automatically if the solution for some parameter gets larger than that (given) value", so I can automatically find those parameters for which the solution gets larger than the given value, by running the for loop once?

Comment: You can attach your own monitoring function to ode45, have you consulted the documentation for the routine?

Answer (score 2):

As [described in the documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/odeset.html#f92-1017470), one can set the `'Event'` property using `odeset`. The following (in an m-file named `ode45EventTest.m`) provides a barebones example of your use case, with the trivial ODE $\frac{dx}{dt} = 1, x(0)=0$:

```
function ode45EventTest
for tMax = [2, 20]
    [~,~,~,~,IE] = ode45(@(t,y) 1, [0 tMax],0,odeset('Event',@myEvent));
    if(isempty(IE))
        fprintf('Threshold not exceeded for tMax = %g\n',tMax);
    else
        fprintf('Threshold exceeded for tMax = %g\n',tMax); 
    end
end

end

function [value,isterminal,direction] = myEvent(~,y)
threshold  = 10;
r          = double(abs(y) > threshold);
value      = r;
isterminal = r;
direction  = 0;
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I would put a switch in the target function, and allow it to write to a file the parameters of interest then switch the output falsely such that the ode45 truncates the run, possibly with a NaN or other.

Do you need some pseudocode?  If so could you provide pseudocode that has some of your info structure and a derivative function that you find useful?

Comment: This is overly complicated when ode45 already has this functionality implemented, as Aron's comment states.

Comment: Here is a link with what I think are more details on the built-in.  http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/ordinary-differential-equations.html#f1-669698

Comment: Although it is nice to know the built-in, it is a little bit of a trap.  The company I work for is a JMP-using house, so my MatLab doesn't translate.  If I use a specialized switch built into a built-in then it is hard to make code that others can find useful.  Why make one-use code ten thousand times?  As I get older I find my sense of accomplishment from such things decreases and I agree more with the ideas of "reproducible research".  http://reproducibleresearch.net/index.php/Main_Page http://cran.r-project.org/web/views/ReproducibleResearch.html